# Hide my application from taskbar

Tags: c#, vb.net, taskbar

Is there is away to hide my application from task bar?

I have tried:

```
Me.Hide()
```

but this hides the form not the application from the task bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one:

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property and set it to `False` in your `Form`.

You can do this in the designer, too:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) property and set to `false`.

For example:

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Comment: its my own answer, not copied from anywhere